# How to print a space if the field is null or blank

Tags: awk

I've a file as x.log

```
07/08/15   05:00:00   07/08/15   05:00:20   DB_XXXLNX9           XXXLNX9    Completed
07/09/15   05:00:00   07/09/15   05:00:34   DB_XXXLNX9           XXXLNX9    Failed
07/10/15   05:00:00   DB_XXXLNX9 BETLNX9    Future
```

I need the columns in the same format printed if any of the fields are null. i.e the DB_XXXLNX9 should be under the above DB_XXXLNX9. For some reason I can't get it to print in this question and I apologize.

```
07/08/15   05:00:00   07/08/15   05:00:20   DB_XXXLNX9           XXXLNX9    Completed
07/09/15   05:00:00   07/09/15   05:00:34   DB_XXXLNX9           XXXLNX9    Failed
07/10/15   05:00:00                         DB_XXXLNX9           XXXLNX9    Future
```

I tried this awk statement

```
awk '{printf "%-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-20s %-10s %-10s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7}' x.log
```

Comment: Thanks fedorqui for formatting the query.

Comment: awk doesn't know you are missing fields. It only sees the fields you actually have. You are going to need to manually pad the fields you want in awk by looking at the columns and doing the work yourself.

Comment: Are the fields tab-separated? If not how **specifically/programatically** can a script tell which fields are missing? Is it always the 2nd date and/or time field that can be missing? If not then show some more diverse input/output.

Comment: The 3rd and 4th field are usually missing 99% of the time

Comment: Does that mean that when any fields are missing it's always those 2 and they are missing in 99% of the lines of your input file or that when any fields are missing then 99% of the time it's those 2 and the other 1% it's some other field(s)? Please edit your question to be clear and specific with truly representative sample input/output of the cases you are looking to solve.

Comment: Ed... yes ..If any fields are missing it's always those 2 i.e the 3rd and 4th field that are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a satisfactory solution, but works fine:

```
 awk '{
    if (NF==5) {
      printf "%-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s %-10s%-10s %-10s\n", $1, $2, "", "", $3, "", $4, $5; }
    else
      print;
}' x.log
```

For incomplete line, the exact space padding is quite strange but needs to fit the OP: note an addtionnal `%-10s` without any space. It's due to the original format.

Note that you cannot simplify this line by using `OFMT` because it's aimed to be used only for floats.

Comment: Thanks Bentoy13 for the solution. The spacing is little off but that's OK.

Answer (score 2):

This may be what you want, it's hard to tell without more information and additional sample input/output:

```
$ awk -v OFS=, 'NF<7{$3=OFS OFS $3} {$1=$1}1' file | column -s, -t
07/08/15  05:00:00  07/08/15  05:00:20  DB_XXXLNX9  XXXLNX9  Completed
07/09/15  05:00:00  07/09/15  05:00:34  DB_XXXLNX9  XXXLNX9  Failed
07/10/15  05:00:00                      DB_XXXLNX9  BETLNX9  Future
```